# WebStorm - IntelliJ - JestJS: How to hide the stack traces in the Test Runner console

Tags: intellij-idea, jestjs, webstorm

**Update**:

This seems to be JestJS related, not WebStorm or IntelliJ.
I found a partial solution (see below) but maybe someone has a full solution.

**Original**:

I am running JestJS tests in WebStorm.

If I use `console.log` or `console.warn` in my code, then I get a full stack-trace and code snippet of the location where the log/warn is issued in the Test Runner console. This is often very handy but can be annoying too.
Is it possible to hide the stack-trace and code-snippet somehow?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found a (partial) solution.

It seems to be Jest which outputs the stack traces and the code snippets.

If I change the Jest CLI options and add `--noStackTrace` then I get a more condense, even acceptable view:

[image]

It would be great to have the possibility to even suppress the 'console.warn' and single 'at TreeState...' lines, though.